# Is it possible for Hadoop MapReduce programs to access local resource?

Tags: hadoop

Could Hadoop framework (or runtime) prevent (or constrain) an application MapReduce program from accessing local resource like local filesystem?

I guess the answer should be true, especially when the MapReduce program is running a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, MapReduce will use local resources in Map/Reduce phase.
The output of Map will be stored in local file system and then suffle and sort will happen.
Next the data will be input to the Reduce phase.
You can specify the path for local path to store the intermediate results of Map by property in Hadoop V1 `mapred.local.dir`

Hadoop V2,
 From the [**Docs**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml),
**Property** :  `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir`
**Value** : `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local`
**Description** : `The local directory where MapReduce stores intermediate data files. May be a comma-separated list of directories on different devices in order to spread disk i/o. Directories that do not exist are ignored.`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A secure (Kerberized) cluster will run containers under the user that submitted the job. Ordinary access control can then isolate this user access to local resources.

Non secure clusters run containers as the NM (I'm talking a modern Yarn cluster, not a 1.x version).

Most recent Hadoop version (2.6, very soon to be released) contains [YARN-1964](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1964) which allows Docker based containers. They are fully isolated (Docker) but this was committed in 2.6 on [2014-11-12](http://xkcd.com/1179/), so is about 2 week mature. You'll be living on the edge.

Comment: Thanks! Does "Kerberized" mean a Hadoop cluster secured by Kerberos?